# how can i get the nearest date values from the current date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

***Events Table***

This is my events table what i need is i need to get the nearest date values from current date.

Current Table

```
--------------- --------------------------------------
events          future_dates      Conversion_Rate
--------------- --------------------------------------
One 1            01-08-2015        1000
One 1            03-08-2015        1000
One 1            06-08-2015        1000
One 1            07-08-2015        1000
One 1            10-08-2015        0
Two 1            13-08-2015        0
Two 1            14-08-2015        0
Two 1            16-08-2015        0
------------------------------------------------------
```

**My Expected Result**

```
--------------- --------------------------------------
events          future_dates      Conversion_Rate
--------------- --------------------------------------
One 1            07-08-2015        1000
One 1            10-08-2015        0
Two 1            13-08-2015        0
Two 1            14-08-2015        0
Two 1            16-08-2015        0
------------------------------------------------------
```

What i have tried so far

```
select * from events where CURDATE() < Conversion_Rate
```

What i need is i need to get the nearest date from current date and where conversion rate != '0'.How can i get the expected result in mysql ?

Comment: Have you misprinted the dates?

Comment: What do you mean by **nearest date**? Is it nearest 5/6 value or nearest date range i.e. within 7 days from today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct you want to fetch a latest record before current date which has a non zero conversion rate along with all other records from current date and later.

If so, a `UNION` may help you as shown in the following example:

```
(
select * from table_name 
 where conversion_rate <> 0 
   and future_dates < current_date
 order by future_dates desc limit 1
) -- this fetches pre cur date recs
union
( -- this fetches cur and post cur date recs
select * from table_name 
 where future_dates >= current_date
)
```

Comment: Superb its almost fixed but it takes the previous result also how can i hide that

Comment: `One 1            01-08-2015        1000
One 1            03-08-2015        1000
One 1            06-08-2015        1000` I dont need this result

Comment: Didn't you apply `order by future_dates desc limit 1` in first part of the `union` ?

Comment: `#1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY ` Im getting this error while i use that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM Table 
WHERE Conversion_Rate != 0
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(future_dates, NOW())) 
LIMIT 10
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Conversion_Rate != 0
ORDER BY ABS(now() - future_dates) DESC
limit 10
```

Comment: but i need the nearest value from the current date and conversionrate != ''

Comment: i need to get both 0 values and != '0' from the nearest date

Comment: try `WHERE Conversion_Rate != 0 and Conversion_Rate = 0 `

Comment: please check my question again

Answer (score 0):

Future_date should be '13/08/2015'. This record should be display today.
I think you may be want this query.

```
select * from events where CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 5 DAY <=future_dates and Conversion_Rate != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from events 
where Conversion_Rate != '0' 
order by ABS(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),future_dates )) asc
```